# Select Unique value related to another column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ project_id ║ document ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║     1      ║    3     ║
║  2 ║     1      ║    5     ║  
║  3 ║     2      ║    3     ║
║  4 ║     2      ║    4     ║
║  5 ║     3      ║    5     ║
║  6 ║     4      ║    2     ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

I want all `project_id` which do not have `document` = 5

In other words, I want this result:

```
╔════════════╗
║ project_id ║
╠════════════╣
║     2      ║
║     4      ║
╚════════════╝
```

Comment: Come on. Try something. Who upvotes this drivel

Comment: I recommend searching for a solution on Google as this is pretty basic logic. All the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT project_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY project_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN document = 5 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b37ebc/1)

Comment: Thanks its a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT DISTINCT project_id FROM project 
WHERE project_id NOT IN(
    SELECT project_id FROM project where document = 5
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer It is a simple version of question if i use subquery that will make a lot loading time[its my thought].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version you can try which uses joins:

```
SELECT t1.project_id
FROM
(
    SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) AS projectCount
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY project_id
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) AS projectCount
    FROM mytable
    WHERE document <> 5
    GROUP BY project_id
) t2
    ON t1.project_id = t2.project_id AND t1.projectCount = t2.projectCount
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72a5e6/1)

Comment: Thanks Tim For your Help